# wistringstream from an xml file to an integer?

Tags: c++, xml, stringstream

```
const XMLDataNode *pointsNode = node->GetChildren().at(0);
std::wistringstream pointsstrm(*pointsNode->GetInnerText());
pointsstrm >> loadedGame.points;
```

This is code I've written to pull an `int` from an XML file and pass it into `loadedGame.points` (an `int`).  However, this isn't working.  It compiles but doens't give the right value.  Why is that?  `XMLDataNode` is a class that manipulates `xmllite.dll`.

Comment: There is information missing - of what type is loadedGame.points, what is the input you feed into the stringstream, what library does XMLDataNode come from?

Comment: loadedGame.points is an integer (listed in the description).  I'll add more to it, though.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what more information you need.  The input fed into strinstream is shown above (it's *pointsNode->GetInnerText()) and loadedGame.points is an integer.  XMLDataNode is a class that makes use of xmllite

Comment: I meant the/one actual string returned by `GetInnerText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Time for some wild guesses!

I'll bet you that the text you get from `*pointsNode->GetInnerText()` isn't what you think it is.  Have you checked that it is indeed exactly the text you want?  In particular, could it contain whitespace?  Parsing a nicely formatted (i.e. indented, broken into lines, etc) XML file without a schema to reference ends up meaning that all sorts text nodes involving whitespace will end up in your DOM tree.

Comment: Though of course, my std::wistringstream (GNU libstdc++6) seems to ignore whitespace when extracting an integer.  There's still a valid concern -- are you sure that what's returned by `*pointsNode->getInnerText()` is what you expect it to be?  A debug print statement might be quite handy here.